# C program code to split integer into it's digits on separate lines with just loops no array

Tags: c, loops

This is my code thus far...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
int x, dg, num, factor;

printf("Enter x:");
scanf("%d",&x);

num=0;
while(x>0)
{
    x/= 10;
    num++;
}
printf("%d is the number of digits",num);//Using number of digits to solve second loop

do
{
    factor = pow(10,num-1);
    dg = x/factor;
    x = x%factor;
}while(factor>0);

printf("\n%d",dg);
}
```

I think there is a problem concerning my second loop if anyone can help please assist me in fixing the code.

The code should take an integer for example 3456 and print the individual digits as

```
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: Please explain the nature of the problem: what *should* the program do for a given input, and what does it do instead.

Comment: Don't use `pow` for integer calculations. Don't use `pow` to just multiply by 10 each iteration.

Comment: @ScottHunter the program takes an integer from the user let's say 3456 and prints it as 

3
4
5
6 
basically printing the individual digits on separate lines

Comment: @JDMukiibs you mean it should print 3 4 5 6 ? Please [edit]  your question and put all clarifications _there_

Comment: @EugeneSh. what should I use instead of pow

Comment: In your current code it's quite unclear. But I imagine that you want to use `* 10`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz thanks I have adjusted the question sorry should have clarified everything

Comment: Yes @EugeneSh...

Comment: Please read the instructions for how to provide an [MCVE]. You should post complete code, after first trying to reduce it to the smallest example which doesn't behave as you think it should. (I.e. we should be able to paste your code into a file and compile it). Thanks!

Comment: @davmac Sure will do thank you... this is my first post... I''m really sorry for the errors

Comment: @JDMukiibs no need to apologise, just be aware that you need to put in a little effort make questions suitable for this site. The questions need to be high quality so they are useful to other readers, also if you do a little legwork people will be much happier to help you. You'll get a good answer if you ask the right way :)

Comment: @davmac Thank you for the pointers. The next time I post I'll definitely make sure to keep this all in mind

Comment: You're not changing `num` each loop of the second while. You need something like `num--` here, or a `num=num-1` after.

Comment: @platinum95 let me try that and get back to you... thank you

Comment: Worth also noting that there are better ways to go about this, but that's one of the issues I spotted in your code. You'll also need to put that last `printf` inside the loop, otherwise you'll just print the last digit.

Comment: @platinum95 is this what you meant::

do
    {
        factor = pow(10,num-1);
        dg = x/factor;
        x = x%factor;
        num--;
    }while(factor>0);

I tried that the program crashed ......

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the first loop in your program, the value of `x` becomes `0`. The input was stored in `x` but no copy was made.

You may make a copy of the number like:

```
scanf("%d", &x);
n = x;
```

Declare a variable `p` to get a power of `10` in it via the first loop as in

```
int p=1;
while(x>0)
{
    x/= 10;
    num++;
    p*=10;
}
p/=10;
```

so that at the end of the loop, `p` will have the value equivalent to `pow(n, num-1)`. The value of `p` is then used in the loop used to display the digits as in

```
for(; num>0; --num, p/=10)
{
    printf("\n%d", (n/p)%10);
}
```

`n/p` is integer division. It will give the leftmost 'y' numbers of `n` where 'y' is

y = `num` - log<sub>10</sub>`p`

In case you are not familiar with `log`, the one above is just a fancy way of saying the number of zeros in `p`.

We then print the last digit of the number obtained by `n/p` with a `%10`.

Comment: I've rewritten that for loop with while and it has run excellently thank you once again everybody